# How do I retrieve scope identity with ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1

My project is using .NET Core 3.1 and I have my stored procedures executing in my repository class. I want to insert and return the scope identity(the id of the record that just inserted `UserNumber`) so I can use it for another stored proc within this same method. The problem I have here is that  `parameters[1].Value` value is returning zero.

Here is an abbreviation of my stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
@iUserNumber            int OUTPUT,
As
    INSERT dbo.tblUser (
        CreatedBy
        )
    VALUES          (@LoginUserId)
IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ERRHANDLER
SET @UserNumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY() /** this is the primary Key **/
RETURN(@UserNumber)
```

Here is a sample of my repository

```
public int InsertUsers(int LoginUserId, int UserNumber)
{
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
    {
            _dbContext.CreateSqlParameter(StoredProcedureConstants.LoginUserId,SqlDbType.Int,LoginUserId.ToSafeInt()),
            _dbContext.CreateSqlParameter(StoredProcedureConstants.UserNumber,SqlDbType.Int,UserNumber.ToSafeInt())                
        }.ToArray();
        var intResult = _dbContext.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureConstants.InsertUsers, parameters);
        var result2 = parameters[1].Value; //This comes back as zero
```

How do I assign the scope identity to `result2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]  
           @LoginUserId int,
           @iUserNumber int OUTPUT
As
    INSERT dbo.tblUser (CreatedBy)
    VALUES             (@LoginUserId)
    SET @iUserNumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY() /** this is the primary Key **/
```

and

```
SqlParameter[] parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
{
   _dbContext.CreateSqlParameter("@LoginuserId",SqlDbType.Int,LoginUserId),
   _dbContext.CreateSqlParameter("@iUserNumber",SqlDbType.Int)                
 }.ToArray();
 parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 _dbContext.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureConstants.InsertUsers, parameters);
 var result2 = parameters[1].Value;
```

Comment: I was damn close to this. I tried to add the parameter output to the end of the `CreateSQLParameter`  and threw a conversion error. Thanks a ton!